# Did the Macintosh OS in 1997 really not have multitasking?

Tags: history, multitasking

In a notice in a local computer magazine from February 1997, they announce that "BeOS" is about to be launched for Macs (or already has been). It's claimed that this can "run several programs at once, so-called 'multi-tasking'" and that this is something that "Apple has never been able to do".

Is this really true? Could Macs in 1997 really only run one program at once? Or is this a misunderstanding? I vividly remember running multiple programs at once in Windows 3.1 on my IBM PC 486, yet "multi-tasking" was boasted as a feature of Windows 95.

Comment: Yes, that was a huge weakness in the Mac platform, and this is a place where Microsoft had lapped Apple with Windows 95. Meanwhile they were also [spiraling toward bankruptcy](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/History_of_Apple_Inc./Progress_in_the_1990s) and lacked capital or frankly, *vision* for a total rewrite of MacOS. You can see where the NeXT acquisition would change that (bringing Steve Jobs and NeXTstep) which became OS X. Now Microsoft was lapped!

Comment: This was being developed but a political decision was made to go another way.   Think that the original iPhone could also only run one app at a time.  Multiple apps and background came later when the hardware became much more powerful.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen There is a significant difference between "running one process at the time" and "running one app at a time". iOS is based on macOS, it always had the ability to run processes in the background. What came later was the ability for apps to keep running (in a controlled manner) without being the visible app.

Comment: @nohillside this was to find a similar situation that OP might have experienced. As always the analogy is approximate. MS-DOS at the time also only ran one application at a time.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica The claim made in OPs post is untrue, Mac OS in 1997 certainly supported multi-tasking. And had done so for a decade, since the introduction of Multifinder in 1987.

Comment: @GlenYates well you always had cdev's and DA's that could do stuff in the background, and Multifinder let applications do that too, a little. But that ability was always a bolt-on, and it was a far cry from proper preemptive multitasking with memory protection and "crash the app, not the PC" as we know it today.

Answer (score 29):

There are several ways to implement multitasking:

- [cooperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking), where processes voluntarily yield control periodically or when idle or logically blocked. This type of multitasking is called cooperative because all programs must cooperate for the scheduling scheme to work
- [preemptive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Preemptive_multitasking), where the operating system (or its scheduler component) actively switches between processes

MacOS versions before OSX only supported cooperative multi-tasking. So yes, it was possible to run several applications at once, but they needed to "behave" and yield control to others. Also, as [Gnasher729](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/97727/gnasher729) and [Mark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/79004/mark) mentioned in the comments, cooperative multitasking between full applications was possible with [Switcher](https://www.folklore.org/StoryView.py?story=Switcher.txt) and from 1987 onwards with [MultiFinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiFinder); prior to that, cooperative multitasking was limited to "desk accessories", a type of lightweight application that piggybacked on the currently-running application.

Comment: For some additional history, cooperative multitasking between full applications arrived in 1987 with [MultiFinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiFinder); prior to that, cooperative multitasking was limited to "desk accessories", a type of lightweight application that piggybacked on the currently-running application.

Comment: For more history, before MultiFinder there was "Switcher", an application that allowed you to select four applications and switch between them. Same principle as multifinder.

Comment: It is *[OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X)*, not *OSX*.

Comment: When limited memory and no hard disk for paging it was practically impossible to fix two full application in memory, hence the small "desk accessories".

Comment: Before preemptive multitasking you had time-sliced multitasking (which preemptive multasking falls back to when all programs demand CPU time). Time-sliced multitasking is when the OS actively switches between processes (what you are describing). Preemptive multitasking is an improvement over time-sliced multitasking where processes that are waiting for I/O events are put to sleep and are **IMMEDIATELY** awaken and given CPU time when the I/O event completes.

Comment: Just for context, CICS (on IBM mainframes) used cooperative multitasking already in the late 60es.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n MacOS was not built to be backward compatible with CICS though.

Answer (score 13):

> Could Macs in 1997 really only run one program at once?
> I vividly remember running multiple programs at once in Windows 3.1.

Well, yes and no.

To *truly* run several programs at once, you need [parallel execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing), which requires a multi-core processor or more than one processor. In 1997, the processors supported by Mac OS (and Windows 3.1) were single-core, so they could indeed only run one program at once. So no.

But both Mac OS and Windows 3.1 used a trick called [multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking) to share the processor time among programs in a way that gave the user the illusion that they were running simultaneously. So yes.

Unfortunately, it was a primitive kind of multitasking, called [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking): programs had to wait until the program currently running would voluntarily release its control of the processor, in the same way you have to wait for someone to leave a packed restaurant to get a table.

Moreover, with cooperative multitasking, if the program that was running crashed, the OS would usually crash too, as it wouldn't have any means to get control back of the processor.

BeOS (and Windows 95) changed that: they switched to [preemptive multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-emptive_multitasking), in which the OS would run a scheduler and share the processor resources among programs, giving them a certain amount of processor time to run. When the time was up, another program would get a time slice to run. That is similar to playing a variant of chess that constrains the amount of time *per move*: you only have that much time to make your move.

All modern server and desktop operating systems use preemptive multitasking. Apple introduced preemptive multitasking in 1997/1998 with Rhapsody (the next-gen OS that would eventually evolve into Mac OS X), and made it available to their main customer base in 2001 with Mac OS X 10.0 (Cheetah).

Comment: re "To truly run several programs at once, you need a multi-core processor." No you can do this with a single core processor

Comment: Today we take multicore processors for granted. In 1997, more likely the motherboard (logic board) would have two individual processors or there would be a rack where units with individual processors could exist.

Comment: Pre-emptive multitasking had been used ion Unix and mainframes long before BeOS and Windows.

Comment: @benwiggy I know, but I'm answering the OP's question, which is about Mac OS, Windows and BeOS, not about OSs in general... Edit: maybe you find the word 'introduced" misleading?

Comment: @mmmmmm It depends on your definition of "at once" and "you can do". If "at once" means "I see on the screen the two programs act at the same time as I as human perceive" then yes, if "at once" means that the CPU is running instructions of both programs *at the same instant in time* and "can do" means "this has actually been implemented commercially" then no, single-core multi-tasking AFAIK always flushed the pipeline/cache etc to ensure a clean context for each program so from instant A to B you *only* have program P1 running and from B to C you *only* have P2, so they do *not* run "at once"

Comment: @GACy20 Yes but the rest of the question says Windows 95 is preemptive multitasking and that ran on a single core processor so the line I commented on does not fit with the rest of the answer.

Comment: @mmmmmm I was trying to make the distinction GACy20 has pointed out in their comment: multitasking is about running tasks concurrently. and you need either a multi-core processor or, alternatively, as I missed in the first version of my answer, more than one processor to do that. If you run tasks sequentially, it's not multitasking.

Comment: @mmmmmm But even when tasks run sequentially, the OS may give the user the *illusion* programs are running at once, in the same way *one single waiter* can provide a good enough experience when serving several customers in a restaurant. The trick is to distribute the processor's (or waiter's) time among all programs (or customers) "fairly". That could be done with cooperative multitasking, but was more reliably achieved with preemptive multitasking, thus the marketing campaign by BeOS.

Comment: You do not need a multi-core or multi-processor system to run multi tasking.  You give the examples of Windows 95 which is a one CPU. You are changing definitions in the middle of the question - I agreee with your answer except that one line

Comment: @mmmmmm I get your point, I conflated the terms parellel execution and multitasking in my answer, I've edited it to make that clear.

Comment: @GACy20 If you want to be truly technically correct its possible to have two separate sets of instructions be fetched from memory and decoded by separate decode pipelines, but running on the same single ALU pipeline. (This is what the pentium 4 HT did, modern processors get a lot more complicated), this is effectively 1 and a half processors. So you do not need a multi-core processor, you just need a processor that supports multiple threads of execution. A subtly different concept.

Comment: @GACy20 Simultaneous multithreading does run several threads within the same core but they still have different permissions, page tables etc. Since most threads don't fully utilize all resources this can be quite effective to hide latencies. Intel ships this in most consumer chips under the brand name Hyper-Threading.

Comment: Oddly enough Windows 3.1 did feature preemptive multi-tasking, but only between its “VMs”: each DOS program running under Windows was preemptively multi-tasked with the running Windows programs, which multi-tasked cooperatively.

Comment: DayStar was making Mac clones in 1995 with quad-core PowerPC CPUs.  https://lowendmac.com/1995/daystar-genesis-mp/.  I don't know how much use MacOS truly made of the extra cores, but it did run MacOS.  (I bought one used in 2001, to mess around with because it seemed cool to have a multi-core machine to run Linux on.  It was super loud with fans and 4x SCSI drives, and a bit flaky (CPU or RAM going bad I think) so I didn't do much with it besides play Escape Velocity under MacOS.)

Comment: BTW, Linux predates BeOS, and has used preemptive multitasking from the start, like *BSD and other Unix systems on m68k and PowerPC which are even older.  (Although IDK if any of them ran well on Apple hardware; Linux ran ok.)

Comment: @idmean: GACy20 said "single-core multi-tasking", not [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading).  They're talking about normal OS context-switching between full processes on a true uniprocessor; the only thing they said wrong is context switches flush cache; basically all modern CPUs use physically tagged cache that doesn't have aliasing problems.  Anyway, an SMT CPU *looks* to the OS like a multi-core system, even if it has only a single physical core, such as Intel Pentium 4.  (As you say, each logical core has separate architectural state, including page tables).

Comment: Multi-core processors are a red herring. They're not required for pre-emptive multi-tasking.  If anything the latter was necessary before the force made much sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes Note sure what you mean. SMT is an example of an architecture where one physical core *is running instructions of both programs at the same instant in time and "can do" means "this has actually been implemented commercially"*, which GACy20 denied. This is what I was responding to. It doesn't matter how it appears to the OS. It is still one physical core.

Comment: @idmean: On a re-read of their comment, yeah maybe that's a useful nitpick.  I'm pretty sure they're *not* intentionally denying the existence of SMT, but rather classifying it as a form of multi-core system, since that's how it looks from the OS perspective; there is no context switch in the first place.  The fact that the logical cores share a phys core doesn't make it UP.  Other less fine-grained HW multitasking (e.g. a "barrel processor") may have the OS give a single core a set of user-space task structures to switch between on stall, instead of actually looking like multiple cores, IDK.

Comment: @idmean: Anyway, yeah, it is true multi-tasking on a single physical core, just not by switching.  Current implementations include Intel, AMD Zen, and IBM POWER.  One of the earliest was Alpha EV8 (https://www.realworldtech.com/alpha-ev8-smt/ / https://www.realworldtech.com/ev8-mckinley/).  Cheap HW switching between HW threads can be done on an in-order machine that rotates between non-stalled threads every cycle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_processor , like apparently the IO processor in CDC 6000.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Barrel processors can be implemented very cheaply in designs that would use delay lines for register storage.  If one had a machine which held all registers in 10us delay lines, and replaced all registers with 100us delay lines, the machine could run ten independent tasks (albeit at at 1/10 the speed) with minimal additional electronics beyond what would be required to initialize the delay-line states.

Comment: Problem with your analogy: playing chess with time controls limits the _total_ time available for all of your moves in a single game, not the amount of time available _per move_.

Comment: @Vikki Thanks for pointing that out, I'm not a chess expert but my understanding was that some chess variants indeed limited the time available per move. I've edited the answer to make that detail clear (apparently bullet chess may work that way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_control#Classification). With that in mind, I think the analogy quite accurately conveys the main aspect of preemptive multitasking: a process must yield control of the CPU after a fixed amount of time. Other analogies I had thought of, like car-sharing, meeting room bookings or take-off slots didn't work as well...